# Is 'status' a keyword in bash?

Tags: bash

On Centos7, I have a Bash script like the following

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello there"
status=$?
```

In my vim editor window, the "status" word is highlighted red, but any other word in its place will be highlighted pink. Is "status" a reserved word in Bash? If so, what's its default purpose?

Comment: I have a `/bin/status`.  Do you get syntax highlighting for other command names?

Comment: Other command names are red but I do not have a /bin/status. `which status` shows no results.

Comment: Short answer: no, `status` is not a keyword in `bash`. The real question is, what about your syntax coloring configuration treats it as one?

Comment: My first thought was that it might be because `$status` is a predefined variable (not a keyword) in csh/tcsh, equivalent to bash's `$?`, but that doesn't seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`status` is not a keyword in `bash`, but `sh.vim` defines it as a keyword in conjunction with its use with various init scripts:

```vim
" From sh.vim, version 139, last updated Oct 09 2015
syn keyword bashAdminStatement daemon killall killproc nice reload restart start status stop
```

At least in its current implementation, `vim` doesn't appear to distinguish `status` as an argument (subcommand) to some other command and `status` as a variable name, leading all uses of `status` to be highlighted as a keyword.

Comment: Every word there does highlight as red. Where is this sh.vim file?

Comment: Nevermind I found it in /usr/share/vim/... from there

Answer (score 1):

See :

```
man status
```

Try in your bash console :

```
 $ status
 unity7 start/running, process 2714
```

It is a current command for system administrator. It is perhaps why vim colors this like that.

Do :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello there"
_status=$?
```

To resolve that.

Comment: I'll go with your underscore naming suggestion for now, but there is no 'status' binary on my system, no man page, and `yum install status` says there's nothing to do. Can I ask which distro you're using?

Comment: What the syntax color of your vim ?

Comment: `which status` -> `/sbin/status`

Comment: `:color` gives default

Comment: It is strange do `:color default` please ?

Comment: Prepending an underscore will turn off the highlighting. but personally I'd just leave it alone and ignore it. Then again I don't use syntax highlighting much.